# how to clear listbox of previous selected radio button from the window after selecting another radio button using tkinker

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

I am an absolute beginner in programming and to Python. I am trying to create a gui using tkinter.
In this program, I want click any radio button and see the list of software name.
Here is the code:

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from pprint import pprint as pp
scope = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds",'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(r"C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Desktop\client_secret.json",scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)
sheet = client.open("soft_list").sheet1 
l1 = sheet.get_all_records() 
 
# Import the required libraries
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

win = Tk()
win.title("Unauthorized Software Detection")
win.geometry("500x400")

# Define a function to get the output for selected option
def selection():
   selected = "Unauthorized software List: " + "\n"
   label.config(text=selected)
   col = sheet.col_values(radio.get())
   listbox = tkinter.Listbox(win)
   listbox.pack(anchor=E)
   j = 0
   for i in col:
        listbox.insert(j, i)
        j = j + 1
   #listbox.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.5, anchor="NE")
radio = IntVar()
Label(text="Welcome to the unauthorized software detection app", font=("Roboto", 15)).pack()
Label(text="The List of Computers:", font=('Aerial 11')).place(x = 40, y = 60)

# Define radiobutton for each options
r1 = Radiobutton(win, text="computer1", variable=radio, value=2, command=selection).place(anchor="nw", x=40, y=90)
r2 = Radiobutton(win, text="Computer2", variable=radio, value=3, command=selection).place(anchor="nw", x=40, y=110)
r3 = Radiobutton(win, text="Computer3", variable=radio, value=4, command=selection).place(anchor="nw", x=40, y=130)


# Define a label widget
label = Label(win)
label.pack(anchor=E)
win.mainloop()
```

when I run this code it shows:

[image]

But the problem is when I select another radio button, the display of listbox from the previous selection still remains.

[image]

How to clear the display of listbox from previous selection and only show the selected radiobutton display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you have created new instance of `Listbox` whenever `selection()` is executed.

You need to create the listbox once and update its content inside the function:

```py
...
# Define a function to get the output for selected option
def selection():
   selected = "Unauthorized software List:"
   label.config(text=selected)
   listbox.delete(0, "end") # clear listbox
   # populate listbox
   col = sheet.col_values(radio.get())
   for i in col:
        listbox.insert("end", i)

...
# Define a label widget
label = Label(win)
label.pack(anchor=E)

# create listbox once
listbox = tkinter.Listbox(win)
listbox.pack(anchor=E)

win.mainloop()
```